# How to get all the pages with beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, pagination, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I want to get the link from all pages, already have this code but when I run the code it always shows error (return self.attrs[key]) KeyError : 'href'. Is anyone can help, thank you. Here is the code :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import requests



url = "http://makeupuccino.com/makeup/faces/foundation?page={}"


def get_url(url):
    req = urllib.request.Request(url)
    return urllib.request.urlopen(req)

link = []
nama = []
merek = []
harga = []
gambar = []
deskripsi = []

page = 1
while (requests.get(url.format(page)).status_code==200):
    res = requests.get(url.format(page))
    print(res.url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,"html.parser")
    items = soup.findAll("div",{"class":"product-block-inner"})
    if len(items)<=1:break #untuk stop ketika produk tidak ditemukan lagi di page selanjutnya
    for item in items:

        new_link = item.find("div",{"class":"image"})
        print(new_link["href"])


    page+=1
```

Comment: You could have much better luck with lxml and xpath like `//a/@href`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have select `div` element which is the parent node of your anchor tag but not the anchor tag which contains the `href` element. You need to add `.a` to the code which is inside the loop.

Something like,

```
print(new_link.a["href"])
```

will give you the links properly.

For proper pagination i can suggest you two ways.

1. Find the number of pages and loop around the pages. In your case the page numbers is given in `page-result` class. You can find the page numbers by the following code.

   `page_numbers = soup.find('div', {'class':'page-result'}).text
   page_numbers = page_numbers.split('(')[-1].replace(' Pages)', '')
   total_pages = ['http://makeupuccino.com/makeup/faces/foundation?page='+str(i) for i in page_numbers] #this list will give you total pages - 4 pages with the link you provided`
2. `break` the while loop when the `There are no products to list in this category.` text appears in page. Deploy this with below code,

   `soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,"html.parser")
   if 'There are no products to list in this category.' in str(soup):
       break
   else:
       #rest of your code.`

Though second solution seems comparatively simple I would suggest you to go with first one as it will teach you many things and it is the appropriate way also.

Hope this helps! Cheers!

Comment: Great help, it works.. but the result of page won;t stop even if it's already reach maximum page.. can you help me?

Comment: Yes. Added the solution to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

div has no attribute href

please try this:

```
new_link = item.find("div",{"class":"image"}).find('a').get('href)
print(new_link)
```